# When Zooming an ImageView the image scales to the corner instead to center

Tags: android, imageview, pinchzoom

So I'm running into an error where the image will zoom, but instead of zooming into the midpoint of my two fingers, it will zoom up to the corner of the original picture. This creates a very unnatural user interface.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

With my onTouchEvent, the myScale.onTouch will send the program to the scaleListener for scaling information

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    midPoint(mid,event);
    myScale.onTouchEvent(event);
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();
                mode=DRAG;
                // Remember where we started
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
           final float gx = myScale.getFocusX();
            final float gy = myScale.getFocusY();
            mLastGestureX=gx;
            mLastGestureY=gy;
            mode=ZOOM;
            break;
        }


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Calculate the distance moved

            if(!myScale.isInProgress()){
                    // Move the object

                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;
                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;

                    // Remember this touch position for the next move event


                    // Invalidate to request a redraw
                    invalidate();

            }
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                break;

            }

I have deleted action up and action pointer up because they have nothing to do with this problems





        }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}






private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}




private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));
        float currentdist=detector.getCurrentSpan();
        float last=detector.getPreviousSpan();
        float ratio = currentdist/last;

        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

        Matrix temp = new Matrix();
        temp.postScale(ratio, ratio, mid.x,mid.y);
        temp.preConcat(matrix);

        matrix=temp;

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Google write a bunch of documentation.  It's a shame it's not the first place people go.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#scale(float, float, float, float)

Answer (score 0):

Use scale (float sx, float sy, float px, float py) insteadOf scale (float sx, float sy)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#scale%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29